# Why doesn't my program display an answer? (Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net

everyone!

I'm currently making a beginners program for converting currencies. Specifically, US Dollars and Pound Sterling. The user enters a value and depending on what start and end currency they choose, it provides an answer in a label. The problem is, the answer wont display in the label. I've attached the code for reference. I've tried a few things but I cant get it. I'm sure you'll all cringe at this code, so feel free to give me other suggestions other than the answer to my question.

```
Dim result As Decimal

Private Sub bt_run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_run.Click
    If cb_start.SelectedValue = "Pound Sterling" And cb_end.SelectedValue = "Pound Sterling" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    ElseIf cb_start.SelectedValue = "Pound Sterling" And cb_end.SelectedValue = "US Dollar" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text * 1.57
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    ElseIf cb_start.SelectedValue = "US Dollar" And cb_end.SelectedValue = "US Dollar" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    ElseIf cb_start.SelectedValue = "US Dollar" And cb_end.SelectedValue = "Pound Sterling" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text * 0.64
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Debug your code step-by-step and see what the values of `cb_start.SelectedValue` and `cb_end.SelectedValue` actually are. They might not be what you're expecting.

Comment: Have you tried .SelectedText instead of .SelectedValue? And please turn Option Strict to ON. It will make your live easier in bigger projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Dim result As Decimal

Private Sub bt_run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_run.Click
    If cb_start.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "Pound Sterling" And cb_end.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "Pound Sterling" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    ElseIf cb_start.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "Pound Sterling" And cb_end.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "US Dollar" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text * 1.57
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    ElseIf cb_start.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "US Dollar" And cb_end.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "US Dollar" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    ElseIf cb_start.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "US Dollar" And cb_end.ddlType.SelectedItem.Text = "Pound Sterling" Then
        result = txt_amount.Text * 0.64
        lbl_ans.Text = result
    End If

End Sub
```

It's similar to what was mentioned in the comments, but the syntax is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is actually with the data-types you are working with.

```
txt_amount.Text 'This is a string value that is returned.
```

Try converting your string to a decimal first before doing math with it.

```
CDec(txt_amount.Text) * 1.57
'And for the other...
CDec(txt_amount.Text) * 0.64
```

Edit:
When putting the decimal value back into your text box, You should probably convert it back to a string.

```
lbl_ans.Text = (CDec(txt_amount.Text) * 1.57).ToString()
```

Edit 2: The following link may be of use to you. This is the Microsoft documentation on datatype conversion.

[Visual Basic Data-Type Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx)

Hope this helps